# How to configure synology NAS for SMTP server

Tags: email, smtp, network-attached-storage, synology

first of all I have to admit that I'm a beginner in this topic. In fact this is my first post.
I have a synology 213J that I want to configure as SMTP server.
I discovered that I needed a domain in order to do that so I generate one using NO-IP.com free service, just testing.
I succeeded in configuring the service in my NAS, but I can't send messages and I don't know which is the smtp of the service that I created.
My question is:
1) it is possible to have a free domain for doing that? I don't want to use google, yahoo or any other service like that. Because with google I succeeded.
2) how to configure my NAS in order to send mails? I tried following the synology.com intructions but they are not clear.

Anybody can help me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your NAS as a regular mail server: Stop right now. It's a NAS, not a mail server and you **really** don't want to expose it to the outside but hide it behind a firewall.

If you want to just send it status mails to you, you don't need a domain, you just have to configure it to use your regular mail account with about any provider that allows authenticated SMTP.

Comment: I need to send about 2000 mails per day to the users of my company for sending the activities.

Comment: Get a real mail server or use some hosted services. Again: A NAS is not a mail server.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He wanted to know if and how to send emails using his NAS.

Comment: @zillaofthegods: First, it appears to have helped the OP, as he accepted my answer. Second: This is a site for professionals and sometimes explaining why you really shouldn't do what you want to do **is** the best possible answer.